# Convert character column into date column (month column)

Tags: r, date, date-format, posixct

I have the following data table, where the column `month` is a `character`-column. I want to convert this into a `date` format.

```
    structure(list(delivYear= c("2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018"
    ), year = c("2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", 
    "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
    "2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
    "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2017", 
    "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
    "2017", "2017", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
    "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018"), q = c("Q1", 
    "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", 
    "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", 
    "Q4", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", "Q4", 
    "Q4", "Q4", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", "Q3", 
    "Q4", "Q4", "Q4", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2", "Q2", "Q3", "Q3", 
    "Q3", "Q4", "Q4", "Q4"), month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
"May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", 
"Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
"May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), nrOrders = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "2", "0", "2", "4", "5", "3", "7", "3", 
    "5", "4", "3", "7", "8", "7", "2", "24", "16", "33", "9", "27", 
    "16", "10", "27", "9", "31", "35", "11", "11", "25", "15", "18", 
    "19", "19", "8", "27", "34", "43", "51", "0", "11", "2", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "4", "5", "1", "0"), eur = c("0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "180", "8760", "17760", "0", "6730", 
    "5354", "2840", "22190", "29210", "8725", "7226", "12500", "2090", 
    "13780", "21434", "15719", "29000", "112366", "38148", "125900", 
    "10285", "54281", "23777", "111512", "76907", "18306", "124393", 
    "103220", "8890", "52082", "119095", "28482", "62841", "54356", 
    "54119", "42999", "112459", "169798", "123808", "504226", "0", 
    "55336", "3017", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "15880", "1844", "252", 
    "0"), yearMonth = c("2014_Jan", "2014_Feb", "2014_Mrz", 
    "2014_Apr", "2014_Mai", "2014_Jun", "2014_Jul", "2014_Aug", "2014_Sep", 
    "2014_Okt", "2014_Nov", "2014_Dez", "2015_Jan", "2015_Feb", "2015_Mrz", 
    "2015_Apr", "2015_Mai", "2015_Jun", "2015_Jul", "2015_Aug", "2015_Sep", 
    "2015_Okt", "2015_Nov", "2015_Dez", "2016_Jan", "2016_Feb", "2016_Mrz", 
    "2016_Apr", "2016_Mai", "2016_Jun", "2016_Jul", "2016_Aug", "2016_Sep", 
    "2016_Okt", "2016_Nov", "2016_Dez", "2017_Jan", "2017_Feb", "2017_Mrz", 
    "2017_Apr", "2017_Mai", "2017_Jun", "2017_Jul", "2017_Aug", "2017_Sep", 
    "2017_Okt", "2017_Nov", "2017_Dez", "2018_Jan", "2018_Feb", "2018_Mrz", 
    "2018_Apr", "2018_Mai", "2018_Jun", "2018_Jul", "2018_Aug", "2018_Sep", 
    "2018_Okt", "2018_Nov", "2018_Dez")), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = c("data.table", 
    "data.frame")
```

How can I handle this to get the `month`-column from character to `date` format?

Comment: If none of these solutions works, please add the code you've tried and did not produce the desired result: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+character+to+date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, if your data.frame is stored in variable `a`, you would do this:

```r
b <- paste(a$year,a$month,"01")
b <- as.Date(b, format = "%Y %B %d")
a <- cbind(a, myDate=b)
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: The problem is: For the months march, may, october and december I get NAs (after step 2). I think here is a problem with the local settings. Furthermore I want to have the same column input as in column ``month`` but when using ``str()``, I want to get date and not character column.

Comment: I would see that this is a problem if you would use the yearMonth column, because there the months are in german abbreviation (e.g. Mrz instead of Mar), but in your month column that is not the case. Never heard of regional settings effecting as.Date(), but you can of course try to replace line 2 with this: `b <- as.Date(gsub("Mar","Mrz",b), format = "%Y %B %d")`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the data table is `dt`, then do this:

```
dt$month = factor(dt$month, levels = month.abb)
```